# If a linear transformation maps each basis vector $e$ into the complement of the span of $e$, then its matrix has diagonal entries all zero

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology

I'm currently reading the proof for Lefschetz fixed point theorem in *Hatcher's Algebraic topology page 179*.

The conclusion in the last lines of the proof relies on the fact that If a linear transformation $f$ maps each basis vector $e$ into the complement of the span of $e$, then its matrix has diagonal entries all zero i.e if $f(e)\cap\langle e\rangle=\emptyset$ where $\langle e\rangle=\{\lambda e:\lambda\in F\}$ then $f$'s matrix has diagonal entries all zero

It seems rather simple, however, I can't seem to understand why.. help would be appreciated.

Comment: The conclusion is true if 'complement' is replaced by 'orthogonal complement'. As it stands , it is false.

Comment: Rather: If $e_1,...,e_n$ is a basis and $\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n$ the dual basis the matrix of $f$ is zero in the diagonal iff $\epsilon_i [f(e_i)]=0$ for all $i$. In other words $f(e_i)$ has no $e_i$-component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may seem rather simple, but it is false. Take, for instance$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R^2&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R^2\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&(x+y,x+y)\end{array}$$and consider the canonical basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$. Then $f(e_1)=f(e_2)=(1,1)$ and, in both cases, $f(e_i)\cap\langle e_i\rangle=\emptyset$. However, the matrix of $T$ with respect to the canonical basis is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I guess I interpreted it wrong. How about if I'll edit the question as follows: If a linear transformation has no fixed point, then its matrix has diagonal entries all zero.

Comment: So, you want to edit your question into another question with respect to which my answer is not an answer anymore. Do you think that that's appropriate?

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I thought It would be less appropriate to ask a new related one. From your response I get that I should ask another one and so I will. I accept your answer to this particular question.